# Finding errors with request

Tags: node.js, node-request

I have a script that posts to an endpoint, like so using the node.js request module https://github.com/request/request

```
const options = {
  url: path,
  formData: {
    name: name,
    bundle: fs.createReadStream(path)
  }
}


request.post(options, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
 if (err) {
  console.log('Error!')
 } else {
  console.log('Success!')
 }
})
```

And I'm trying to catch when the post fails and doesn't work. I tried purposely uploading something and got a `400` response back, but it still came back with success. Is there a more appropriate way to handle error catching with the request module?

Comment: Check the actual `httpResponse.statusCode`.  I don't think request populates `err` unless the request literally fails, as in doesn't arrive or has a network transmission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request library doesn't populate the `error` argument of the request callback unless there is an actual error in the transmission or some other runtime issue.  See this issue on the GitHub: [404 error does not cause callback to fail #2196](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2196).

> Currently request does not handle the HTTP errors. You can wrap the
>   callback and add your own logic there.

To check for HTTP errors, check the `statusCode` property of the `response` argument:

```
request.post(options, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err || httpResponse.statusCode >= 400) {
        return console.error("Something went wrong");
    }
    console.log('Success!')
});
```